# how to send requests inside loop to backend and use await and make the loop executes sequentially

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have an array list of sizes which i want to create in the database so i loop on the array and send a request for each item in the array using await to get the response , the problem is the async part takes too much time the loop continues execution and when it ends the method returns size_group with an empty array, also the array get filled after the return but the returned data is empty

```
add(body) {
    let sizeGroup = null;
    let sizes = null;
    return god.post('/size_groups', body)
        .then((response) => {
            sizeGroup = response.data.size_group;
            for (var i = 0; i < body.sizes.length; i++) {
                let size = {
                    'name': body.sizes[i].label,
                    'size_group': sizeGroup._id
                };
                (async () => {
                    let response2 = await god.post('/sizes', size);
                    if (response2.data.status === true)
                        sizeGroup.push(response2.data.size);
                })();
            }
            return sizeGroup;
        });
}
```

Comment: Please reformat the code snippet to make it more readable

Comment: sorry for that , done

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is one of few problems that `async..await` solves. Since `async` functions are supported in current environment, there's no reason to combine them with promise chains, the entire function should be converted to `async`:

```
async add(body) {
    const response = await god.post('/size_groups', body)
    let sizeGroup = response.data.size_group;
    for (var i = 0; i < body.sizes.length; i++) {
        let size = {
            'name': body.sizes[i].label,
            'size_group': sizeGroup._id
        };
        let response2 = await god.post('/sizes', size);
        if (response2.data.status === true)
            sizeGroup.push(response2.data.size);
    }
    return sizeGroup;
}
```